# Delegating Azure Active Directory Roles When Calling API from SPA

Tags: azure, single-page-application, azure-active-directory, adal, rbac

I have a single page application (SPA) and an API. Both are secured using Azure Active Directory using role based access control (RBAC). I can login and viewview my SPA using ADAL. I can also login, call my API and see the role claims I have given myeself.

I want to call the API from the SPA. I have added the API delegated permissions to the SPA. I have also hit the 'Grant Permissions' button so I don't see a consent screen.

The problem is when the SPA calls the API, no role claims appear, so the API always returns a 403 Forbidden response. How can I solve this?

### Update

This is the manifest for my API:

```
{
  "appId": "[API Client ID]",
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Read Device",
      "id": "b2e6f6c2-c3d5-4721-ad49-0eea255ccf45",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Can read a device.",
      "value": "Device.Read.All"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

In my SPA, I'm using ADAL and adal-angular like so:

```
var azureActiveDirectory = {
    'instance': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    'tenant': '[My Tenant ID]',
    'clientId': '[SPA Client ID]',
    'redirectUri': 'http://localhost:8080/',
    'endpoints': {
      'http://localhost:5000': '[API Client ID]'
    }
adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(azureActiveDirectory, $httpProvider);
```

Comment: How are the roles defined on the API in its manifest? Also, could you show how you are getting the token in the SPA?

Comment: @juunas Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, roles in nested groups are not transitive i.e. If I am a member of Group 2, I do not have the Role granted to Group 1, even though Group 2 is a member of Group 2:

- Group 1

  - Has a Role from Application 1
  - Has a Member called Group 2

This is absolutely unbelievable that such a feature has not been implemented. I've raised a suggestion on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18678670-support-inheriting-roles-in-nested-groups). Please upvote the suggestion.

Comment: This is an unrelated question, but is there a way to reuse the app roles which are defined in a spa app, from its api app, without duplicating?

Answer (score 0):

you should create the appRole in your API app, when your spa call API, it will get access token with the role in api app that the login user belongs to. so to make sure you create role and verify role in api app, not spa app.

Comment: All my roles are in my API app.